# How to remove the extension library from an application

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an application developed in 8.5 using a few elements from the extension library.

The server has been upgraded with the extension library applied each upgrade.

With the extension library now part of the code base there is no need to have it installed on top of the Domino installation, however the application cannot be edited unless it is applied.

How do we remove the extension library from the application?

That said, can I install the extension library on a Domino v10 server?

I have checked the extension library website and there is no reference to ND10 and using the extension library.  This is not really downloaded much anymore which is why I feel I should remove this dependency my application has.

I am currently getting the error 'Could not load the page /cc_input.xsp because the corresponding class xsp.Cc_005finput was not a com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDispatcher.'  This error points to the issue being with the missing extension library.

```
I have checked what is installed, and this is the output:

tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib
[16F8:0002-21FC] 19/04/2019 05:18:34 PM  osgi "Framework is launched."
[16F8:0002-21FC] 19/04/2019 05:18:34 PM  id     State       Bundle
[16F8:0002-21FC] 19/04/2019 05:18:34 PM  171    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_10.0.1.v00_00_20181128-2143
[16F8:0002-21FC] 19/04/2019 05:18:34 PM  172    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_10.0.1.v00_00_20181128-2143
[16F8:0002-21FC] 19/04/2019 05:18:34 PM  173    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_10.0.1.v00_00_20181128-2143
[16F8:0002-21FC] 19/04/2019 05:18:34 PM  174    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_10.0.1.v00_00_20181128-2143
[16F8:0002-21FC] 19/04/2019 05:18:34 PM  175    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_10.0.1.v00_00_20181128-2143
[16F8:0002-21FC] 19/04/2019 05:18:34 PM  176    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational_10.0.1.v00_00_20181128-2143
[16F8:0002-21FC] 19/04/2019 05:18:34 PM  177    STARTING    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.sample_10.0.1.v00_00_20181128-2143
[16F8:0002-21FC] 19/04/2019 05:18:34 PM  178    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib_10.0.1.v00_00_20181128-2143
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension Library is part of Domino since 9.0.1 FP10. From the error message, it seems like you're misunderstanding what needs installing where for what purpose.

`tell http osgi ss` and `tell http osgi diag` issued on a server console show what's running on the server. They're required for a **successfully compiled** application to run on the server.

Looking at the error message, the likelihood is that the application is not successfully compiled and the errors you're seeing are in Domino Designer as well as / instead of the Domino server.

I suspect it's also a high likelihood that the application has been opened in DDE with Build Automatically enabled. If that happens and the plugins it's dependent on are missing, the application gets recompiled and the result is an **unsuccessfully compiled** application, which means it no longer runs anywhere until **successfully compiled**.

The error message is almost certainly nothing to do with Extension Library, it's core plugins missing from DDE that last compiled the application. See https://openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=JGAR-B9QL8B.

Under the strongest terms I would advise against developing without the XPages Extension Library. You'll also have a sub-optimal user experience and are likely to hit problems developers haven't encountered for over five years. And if you remove it from an existing application, you'll likely have to do significant redevelopment.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond so thoroughly.  I had assumed that the extension library separate install vs it being included might have been an issue but clearly is not.  I have no intention of removing the library.